# What do these issues mean when I analyze my application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, memory-management

When I chose the Product | Analyze menu option in Xcode, I see results like the following for my application:

[image]

What does this analysis report mean?

Answer (score 5):

If you store a value to a local variable, but then never make use of that variable, its a dead store (not a big deal ) but why are you saving a value and then not use it?

example of dead store:

```
NSString *hello = [NSString alloc]init]; <- dead store
hello = @"World";
```

removing dead store:

```
NSString *hello; <- dead store fixed
hello = @"World";
```

Comment: it means if i used method Local variable then is it oki?

Comment: @jrturton :

can you give me an example ?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/featuredarticles/StaticAnalysis/FeaturedArticle.html

Comment: Actually in fairness to @zirk, his code example is a memory leak _and_ a dead store, but it is a confusing example because of that.

Comment: Its actually an example of both a dead store & memory leak :p

Comment: @zirk - yes, apologies! Look at those comment times :)